# Is the advertised Horse Power rating of a dc motor correct?

Tags: power, dc

Garage door opener is being advertised with a 1.25 hps dc motor at 120v and 200w.  Is the horse power rating correct?

Comment: ... academic work without an attempt.

Comment: And a really annoying to read title.

Comment: @OlinLathrop: Since you've already taken the time to write both an answer and a comment, why not go ahead and edit the title?

Comment: @Dave: Because that would deprive others seeing the OP's sloppy attitude, which might influence whether and how they might vote on the question or answer it.

Comment: @OlinLathrop: I don't understand your logic. As you well know, this site is all about the questions and their answers, not the people. You obviously thought that the question was worth answering, so why wouldn't you want to make it more readable?

Comment: Learn to include link to motor specs in question and use  proper "caps" for abbreviated units.  200W "might" be typical power used on a smooth door slide, but then that equates to 1/4 hp (incl. loss) so it has reserve power for momentary stiffness and starting.

Comment: It depends on the horse...

Answer (score 1):

Consumer products that have horsepower listed are usually rated in "peak Hp." That is the power that they can produce for a brief time before they overheat and fail. The motor is probably thermally protected so that it can produce less that 1/4 Hp while operating normally, but shut itself off if it produces more than that for very long.

A motor that has no losses would require 1.25 X 746 = 932 watts of electrical power. A small motor in a consumer product is likely to be between 60% and 80% efficient. So 932 / .7 = 1300 watts would be required for 1.25 Hp. For 200 watts input, the motor could produce about 0.7 X 200 / 746 = 0.19 Hp.

Comment: It is not rated in hp though.. it's rated in hps. Which is quite different. See my answer.

Comment: @Trevor I took hps to be a typo and also had doubts about the motor actually being DC. There was something about the presentation of the question that led be to that. Given your answer, I suspect that the HPS rating is similar to the "Peak Hp" rating often seen on motorized consumer products in terms of being technically correct in some devious way but really just marketing hype.

Answer (score 0):

One electrical horsepower is equal to 746 watts.
So, 1.25HP=932W

Answer (score 0):

The horse power rating, though pretty uncommon for electric machines, is typically a measure for the *mechanical power* of a device (e.g. a car motor, a garage door opener drive), ie. the power coming out of the motor (after being converted from electrical to mechanical form).

The 200W (capital W!) on the other hand is the *electrical power*. Not all power that goes into the electric motor can come out as mechanical power. There's always going to be some losses, so that

$$\frac{P_{out}}{P_{in}}< 1\tag 1$$

I think you should be able to look up the conversion from horse power to watt yourself, really, but since you asked:

$$1\,\text{hp}= 745.699871582\,\text W$$

Enter that into the formula \$(1)\$ and check whether the claim is physically possible.

Answer (score 0):

Note it says 1.25HP**S**

From a manufacturer website...

> HPS (Horse Power Similar) is a designation indicating the high-quality DC motor in this garage door opener features pulling force similar to a 1-1/4 horsepower AC motor. This designation is provided for comparison purposes since DC motors are not typically measured in horsepower.

Basically the value shown is a marketing number. It is intended to give you a practical measure that allows you to compare one model against another. It has no mathematical connection to the actual power usage of the motor.

If the description above is to be taken literally, the value indicated is more about force than power. In which case the gearing ratio matters.

Answer (score -1):

Horsepower is just another unit of power.  Power is energy per time.  In the MKS system, energy is measured in Joules and time in seconds.  Power is measured in Watts, which is Joules/second.

Horsepower preceeds Watts.  When James Watt (yes, the same guy the Watt was eventually named for) invented the steam engine, he needed a way to describe how much work a steam engine could do in terms his potential customers could understand.  He did this by measuring how fast horses could pull a rope that went over a pully and lifted a weight up a well shaft.  His physics was right, but it seems he converged on a measure that most horses can't sustain for long.  Nonetheless, horespower became the unit used to quantify the output of steam engines, and later many other things.

When the metric system came along, it was determined that a horsepower was 745.7 Joules/second.  That is now the definition of the horsepower.  Since power is a common unit, the Joule/second was given its own name.  This name is the Watt, in honor of James Watt.

### Unambiguous answer to question

From the above, it should be obvious that 200 W = 0.27 horsepower, and that 1.25 horsepower = 932 W.  Clearly there is a discrepancy somewhere.  This discrepancy is much larger than inefficiency would explain.

If the specs listed in the question are really what is claimed, then *maybe* a 1¼ horsepower motor is used, but it is not actually run at that power.

A more likely explanation is that "1.25" is really supposed to be "0.25".  There was a typo copying a value perhaps.  The 186 W implied by "0.25 horsepower" is close enough to the stated 200 W input power claim to not be inconsistant.  There is little point rating a appliance at a very specific value like "186 W".  It's better to round up to "200 W".  It gives you a little more room to cover your butt, and you're not going to lose any customers that would have bought the unit if it only took 186 W, but think that 200 W is too much.  200 W may also be the electrical input power, and 186 W the mechanical output power.

Comment: Besides which, this is not an answer to the actual question.

Comment: @Dave: I thought I gave enough info so the op could work things out himself, but apparently not.  See addition to the answer.